# Kirchhoff's circuit laws - regular tetrahedron

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I would like to ask for help in following exercise. I have tried to solve it, but I don't know if it is correct.

In every edge of regular tetrahedron is placed resistor `R` and to two vertices there is connected electromotive force unit `U`. Write Kirchhoff's circuit laws for this circuit, determine electric current for branches and electrical resistance between two random vertices of tetrahedron.

My first picture:

[image]

Then I have modified it to this
[image]

And finally I have added direction of current
[image]

From the equations I have got this results:

- electrical current between `Ic` and `Id` is equal to 0
- node A: `I1 - I3 - I4 = 0`
- node B: `I8 + I9 - I10 = 0`
- node C: `I4 + I7 - I8 = 0`
- node D: `I3 + I7 - I5 - I6 = 0`
- node X: `I - I1 - I2 = 0`
- node Y: `I2 + I10 - I11 = 0`

Electrical current in node IA:

```
I2R = -Ue
```

Electrical current in node IB:

```
-I2R + I4R + I8R = 0
```

Electrical current in node IC:

```
I3R + I6R - I4R - I7R = 0
```

For `I3R = I4R` and `I6R = I7R`, I have got equation `0 = 0`
Electrical current in node `ID`:

```
I5R + I7R - I6R - I8R = 0
```

And for `I6R = I7R` and `I5R=I8R`, I have got equation `0 = 0`

Is this solution correct, or am I somwehere wrong?

Comment: I7 is not I6, it is I7 = -I6; so for node D only: I3 - I6 - I5 = 0

Comment: Best way is nodal analysis using the original circuit diagram. There are only two unknown nodes, and the simultaneous equations are easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll rather "hint" you in the right direction to help you employ the right methods than solve it completely, I think you'll enjoy that more!

This gets doable if you start with your first schematic, and apply the Y-Delta transformation on the "inner" three R (those who connect to C). Afterwards, you will have two parallel triangles, and can d simplify the "double edges" individually.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your redrawn circuit, I can see that

- I5 and I9 are the same current, labelled twice.
- By symmetry, I3 = I4 = I5 = I8
- By symmetry, I6 = I7 = 0